# VirtualBox Error: Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_LDR_MISMATCH_NATIVE)

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

I am using Genymotion for Android virtual device and it works 2-3 months and now am getting error VirtualBox Cannot start the virtual device. I tried  all the solution but issue not resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had to lower my virtual device memory and then it worked.